# iphone select control

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Is the select control available as an API? when you select text you are presented with cut/copy..options I would like to add another one. is it possible if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a [`UIMenuController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html), which has a property called [`menuItems`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008301-CH1-SW17), which is `nil` by default (no custom items), but you can add new [`UIMenuItems`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMenuItem_Class/Reference/MenuItem.html) to it.

Comment: can i delete the default options?

Comment: I wouldn't know without trying; the docs make it sound like you can't, but I'd have to experiment to be sure.

Comment: one more question: can I use UIMenuController to change the default behavior of the context menu of  UIWebView? I want to add "Email Selection"

Comment: @Lisa I'd imagine so. The `UIMenuController` is a singleton, so if you add a new item to it, it'll show up wherever the menu shows up, including a webview.  Then somewhere along the responder chain you'll have to implement the method your menuItem needs in order to `emailSelection:`